# using MultiSelect widget to hide and show lines in bokeh

Tags: python, python-2.7, widget, bokeh

I'm working with four sets of data, each of them have several number of time series. i'm using bokeh for plotting all of them together, the result looks like this:

[multiline graph bokeh with widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Azi.png)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlGn4
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, MultiSelect
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox

output_file("graph.html")
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime", title="title")
cdn = range(4)
for i,comp in enumerate(cdn):
    ts=[t for t in data_plu_price.columns if int(t) in df.T[df.C==comp].values]
    n_lines=len(data[ts].columns) 
    p.multi_line(xs=[data[ts].index.values]*n_lines, ys=[data[t].values for t in ts],line_color=RdYlGn4[i], legend=str(i))
p.title.align = "center"
p.title.text_font_size = "20px"
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'date'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'val'

callback = CustomJS("""Some Code""")
multi_select = MultiSelect(title="Select:", value=cdn,
                       options=[(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(4)])
layout = row(p,widgetbox(multi_select))
show(layout)
```

The problem is it looks really messy, so I wanted to use the multiselect widget to show/hide all the groups of multilines(4).  how to use the multiselect widget with a `multi_line` plot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for doing exactly that (using a MultiSelect widget to hide/show lines) was just added in version 0.12.1 in this PR: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4868

There's an example here (copied below): https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/line_on_off.py

```
""" Example demonstrating turning lines on and off - with JS only

"""

import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("line_on_off.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

code = """
    if (0 in checkbox.active) {
        l0.visible = true
    } else {
        l0.visible = false
    }
    if (1 in checkbox.active) {
        l1.visible = true
    } else {
        l1.visible = false
    }
    if (2 in checkbox.active) {
        l2.visible = true
    } else {
        l2.visible = false
    }
"""

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend="Line 1", **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend="Line 2", **props)

callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={})
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"], active=[0, 1, 2], callback=callback, width=100)
callback.args = dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox)

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

Comment: there was a problem with the implementation of the listener, you can try the original code yourself and check that the boxes dont hide the lines that must to, maybe was a crossbrowsing problem with js and chrome.
if you change all the sentences ´(1 in checkbox.active)´ with ´checkbox.active.includes(1)´ that will do the job.
even tho, the answer was really helpful

Comment: the `checkbox.active.includes` results in `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'
File: Function code (1), Line: 3, Column: 5` on IE11

Comment: and I agree with @pablo-a his comment. This doesn't hide the correct lines, just the first *n* lines that are selected, so if you select lines 0 and 2 it shows 0 and 1 (the first 2)

Comment: I don't know enough of javascript, but might this be due to to `in` checking in the keys os the Array instead of the values?

Comment: that was indeed the problem. Instead of testing `0 in checkbox.active` you should test `checkbox.active.indexOf(0) > -1`