# Enable lines in Bokeh using Multiselect

Tags: javascript, python, multi-select, bokeh

I read out loggers with time and humidity data on a few locations. To explore the data and distribute it I use Python (via jupyter notebook) and Bokeh.
To simplify the data exploration I want to be able to enable and disable the I read out loggers with time and humidity data on a few locations. To explore the data and distribute it I use Python (via jupyter notebook) and Bokeh.
To simplify the data exploration I want to be able to enable and disable the graphs of locations (and in the future also humidity and/or temperature). To do this I want to use [multiselect](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html#bokeh.models.widgets.inputs.MultiSelect).

I got so far as to select multiple lines, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706613/1562285), but when I try it, it picks the first *n* locations, not the ones I selected.

### Imports

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Set1_6
from bokeh.plotting import figure as bf
from bokeh.models import MultiSelect, CustomJS, Range1d, LinearAxis, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.resources import CDN
output_notebook()
```

### Helper functions

One function generates example data

```
def generate_example_data(x, param=1):   
    t = 20 + param + np.sin(x * (1 + param))
    rh = 50 + param + 10 * np.tan(x * (1 + param))
    return {"x": x.copy(), "t": t, "rh": rh}
```

Another function generates the javascript code to make a line visible or invisible. I tried a few ways, but none give correct results. I also added logging to be able to see what happens and which if-else clauses get triggered.

```
def generate_selector_code(locations):
    for index, location in enumerate(locations):
        res_str = """    if (%(index)i in multiselect.attributes.value) {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
        console.log('enabling0 %(loc)s' );
    } else {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
        console.log('disabling0 %(loc)s' );
    }
    if ('%(index)i' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
        console.log('enabling1 %(loc)s' );
    } else {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
        console.log('disabling1 %(loc)s' );
    }
    if ('%(loc)s' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
        console.log('enabling2 %(loc)s' );
    } else {
        %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
        %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
        console.log('disabling2 %(loc)s' );
    }
    """%({"index": index, "loc": location})
# other method's I've tested but which result into an error which states that Object does not have an attribute includes
#     if (multiselect.attributes.value.includes('%(index)i')) {
#         %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
#         %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
#         console.log('enabling3 %(loc)s' );
#     } else {
#         %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
#         %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
#         console.log('disabling3 %(loc)s' );
#     }
#     if (multiselect.attributes.value.includes('%(loc)s')) {
#         %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
#         %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
#         console.log('enabling4 %(loc)s' );
#     } else {
#         %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
#         %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
#         console.log('disabling4 %(loc)s' );
#     }

        yield res_str
```

### Setting up the plot

Generates the example data and selects which tools to use

```
locations = ["loc_one", "loc_two", "loc_three"]
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 20)
data_per_loc = OrderedDict()
for i, loc in enumerate(locations):
    data_per_loc[loc] = generate_example_data(x, i)

tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,resize,save,crosshair,hover,xbox_zoom, wheel_zoom"
```

### Generating the plot

The function which does the actual plot generation. It creates the actual Bokeh figure and concatenates the javascript code to enable or disable the different lines

```
def generate_plot(data_per_loc):
    palet = itertools.cycle(Set1_6)
    p = bf(title="test", plot_height=500, plot_width=1000, tools=tools, y_range=(17, 27), 
       toolbar_location="above")
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "x"

    p.yaxis.axis_label = "Temperature [°C]"
    p.extra_y_ranges = {"humidity": Range1d(start=30, end=80)}
    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="humidity", axis_label="Relative Humidity [%Rh]"), 'right')

    plot_locations = OrderedDict()
    for location, datadict in data_per_loc.items():
        colour = next(palet)
        source = ColumnDataSource(datadict)
        t = p.line(x='x', y='t', color=colour, source=source, legend=location)
        rh = p.line(x='x', y='rh', source=source, color=colour,
               legend=location, y_range_name='humidity',
               line_dash="dashed", )
        plot_locations.update({location+"_t": t, location+"_rh": rh})

    code = "console.log('value: ' + multiselect.attributes.value);\n " + "console.log('value_type: ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(multiselect.attributes.value).slice(8, -1));\n " +             "console.log('options: ' + multiselect.attributes.options);\n " + "".join(generate_selector_code(data_per_loc.keys()))
    return p, code, plot_locations
```

The resulting code looks like this:

```
"console.log('value: ' + multiselect.attributes.value);
 console.log('value_type: ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(multiselect.attributes.value).slice(8, -1));
 console.log('options: ' + multiselect.attributes.options);
 if (0 in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_one_t.visible = true;
    loc_one_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling0 loc_one' );
} else {
    loc_one_t.visible = false;
    loc_one_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling0 loc_one' );
}
if ('0' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_one_t.visible = true;
    loc_one_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling1 loc_one' );
} else {
    loc_one_t.visible = false;
    loc_one_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling1 loc_one' );
}
if ('loc_one' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_one_t.visible = true;
    loc_one_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling2 loc_one' );
} else {
    loc_one_t.visible = false;
    loc_one_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling2 loc_one' );
}
    if (1 in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_two_t.visible = true;
    loc_two_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling0 loc_two' );
} else {
    loc_two_t.visible = false;
    loc_two_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling0 loc_two' );
}
if ('1' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_two_t.visible = true;
    loc_two_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling1 loc_two' );
} else {
    loc_two_t.visible = false;
    loc_two_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling1 loc_two' );
}
if ('loc_two' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_two_t.visible = true;
    loc_two_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling2 loc_two' );
} else {
    loc_two_t.visible = false;
    loc_two_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling2 loc_two' );
}
    if (2 in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_three_t.visible = true;
    loc_three_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling0 loc_three' );
} else {
    loc_three_t.visible = false;
    loc_three_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling0 loc_three' );
}
if ('2' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_three_t.visible = true;
    loc_three_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling1 loc_three' );
} else {
    loc_three_t.visible = false;
    loc_three_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling1 loc_three' );
}
if ('loc_three' in multiselect.attributes.value) {
    loc_three_t.visible = true;
    loc_three_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling2 loc_three' );
} else {
    loc_three_t.visible = false;
    loc_three_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling2 loc_three' );
}
"
```

### First attempt at bringing it together

```
output_file("c:\html\multiselect_loc.html")
p, code, plot_locations = generate_plot(data_per_loc)

ms_options = locations
ms_value = locations

callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={})
multiselect = MultiSelect(title="Location:", options=ms_options, value=ms_value, callback=callback)
callback.args = dict(**plot_locations, multiselect=multiselect)


layout = row(p, multiselect)
show(layout)
```

### Second attempt at bringing it together

I thought perhaps the javascript had problems with the strings as values, so I tried using ints as values for the multiselect

```
output_file("c:\html\multiselect_val.html")
p, code, plot_locations = generate_plot(data_per_loc) 

ms_options = [(str(i), v) for i , v in enumerate(locations)]
ms_value = [str(i) for i in range(len(locations))]

callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={})
multiselect = MultiSelect(title="Location:", options=ms_options value=ms_value, callback=callback)
callback.args = dict(**plot_locations, multiselect=multiselect)


layout = row(p, multiselect)
show(layout)
```

### The results

Bokeh plotted the lines without problems, but the selection acted weird. Instead of showing the locations I wanted, it gave the first *n* lines with first 2 selection methods, and nothing with the 3rd.

The javascript console returns something like:

```
value: loc_two
value_type: Array
options: loc_one,loc_two,loc_three
enabling0 loc_one
enabling1 loc_one
disabling2 loc_one
disabling0 loc_two
disabling1 loc_two
disabling2 loc_two
disabling0 loc_three
disabling1 loc_three
disabling2 loc_three
value: loc_two,loc_three
value_type: Array
options: loc_one,loc_two,loc_three
enabling0 loc_one
enabling1 loc_one
disabling2 loc_one
enabling0 loc_two
enabling1 loc_two
disabling2 loc_two
disabling0 loc_three
disabling1 loc_three
disabling2 loc_three
```

[image: the results set in a table]

I've added all example code on my github repo [my github repo](https://github.com/vadella/bokeh-multiselect), as well as the javascript console outputs. All this was tested with IE11 (company restrictions).

Comment: might this be because `in` checks for in the keys of the array, and not the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the culprit, and it is indeed the fact in checks in the keys of the array (0 to len-1) instead of the values

```
    res_str = """\
if (multiselect.attributes.value.indexOf('%(loc)s')>-1) {
    %(loc)s_t.visible = true;
    %(loc)s_rh.visible = true;
    console.log('enabling5 %(loc)s' );
} else {
    %(loc)s_t.visible = false;
    %(loc)s_rh.visible = false;
    console.log('disabling5 %(loc)s' );
}
"""%({"index": index, "loc": location})
```

is the correct test in `def generate_selector_code(locations):`

I noticed this when reviewing the code in [the bokeh example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/line_on_off.py) which uses `CustomJS.from_coffeescript()` and browsing throught the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)

```
of  => in 
in  => no JS equivalent
```

Answer (score 0):

another method would be to use `CustomJS.from_coffeescript()` and change the code from JS to CoffeeScript

```
res_str = """\
if '%(loc)s' in multiselect.attributes.value
    %(loc)s_t.visible = true
    %(loc)s_rh.visible = true
    console.log 'enabling %(loc)s'
} else {
    %(loc)s_t.visible = false
    %(loc)s_rh.visible = false
    console.log 'disabling %(loc)s'
}
"""%({"index": index, "loc": location})
```