# hide annotations in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh plot where I add some data in the form of a LabelSet and BoxAnnotation as overlay, but I want to be able to dynamically enable/disable this overlay.

I can enable/hide some of the lines in the plot [already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40592165/1562285), but the system for the Annotations seems to be different. I've got so far already

## Initialising

```
from ipywidgets import interact
from bokeh.plotting import figure as bf
from bokeh.layouts import layout as bl
from bokeh.models import Toggle, BoxAnnotation, CustomJS
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()
```

## Widget generation

```
p = bf(title='test', x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))
x = [1/3, 2/3]
y=[1/3, 2/3]
p.circle(x=x, y=y, size=15)

box = BoxAnnotation(left=None, right=0.5, fill_color='red', fill_alpha=0.1)

p.add_layout(box)
```

## Interactivity

```
code = '''\
if toggle.active
    box.visible = true
    console.log 'enabling box'
else
    box.visible = false
    console.log 'disabling box'
'''
callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(code=code, args={})
toggle = Toggle(label="Red Box", button_type="success", callback=callback)
callback.args = {'toggle': toggle, 'box': box}

layout = bl([p], [toggle])
show(layout)
```

When I check the JS console, the if/else clauses get triggered as expected, so the `Toggle` works but the red box stays in place, both in Firefox as in IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there might be some plumbing that is not hooked up on the BokehJS side to respond to `visible`. If so, that's a bug. Please make an issue with all this information in the [Project Issue Tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

In the mean time, you can accomplish the same visual effect by manipulating the `alpha` values instead:

```
code = '''\
if toggle.active
    box.fill_alpha = 0.1
    box.line_alpha = 1
    console.log 'enabling box'
else
    box.fill_alpha = 0
    box.line_alpha = 0
    console.log 'disabling box'
'''
callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(code=code, args={})
toggle = Toggle(label="Red Box", button_type="success", callback=callback)
callback.args = {'toggle': toggle, 'box': box}

layout = bl([p], [toggle])
show(layout)
```