# bokeh checkbox doesn't correspond to the right line in the plot

Tags: python, checkbox, bokeh

I am trying to add the checkbox in my bokeh plot so that I can hide or show different lines in my plot. I found the following code in the bokeh github which is exactly for this:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("line_on_off.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

p = figure()
props = dict(line_width=4, line_alpha=0.7)
x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
l0 = p.line(x, np.sin(x), color=Viridis3[0], legend="Line 0", **props)
l1 = p.line(x, 4 * np.cos(x), color=Viridis3[1], legend="Line 1", **props)
l2 = p.line(x, np.tan(x), color=Viridis3[2], legend="Line 2", **props)

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 1, 2], width=100)
checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2,     checkbox=checkbox),
                             code="""
                                  l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
                                  l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
                                  l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
                                  """)

layout = row(checkbox, p)
show(layout)
```

It can generate the "line_on_off.html" with the interactive function. However, if I uncheck one box, whichever it is, l2 is always the one hidden. If I uncheck two boxes, whichever they are, l1 and l2 are always the one hidden.

I also tried the other code which will generate the same plot on bokeh server and that works as intent. But I hope to save it as an offline file with the interactive function instead keeping running a server.

Any ideas why it doesn't behave correctly in the offline file?

Comment: I think this was a bug fixed in a recent version. Please always, always, always provide version information when asking questions.

Comment: From my expierience it is not so much a bug in Bokeh as the way `JavaScript`s `in` works

Comment: The example code inthe bokeh github uses `CustomJS.from_coffeescript(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, checkbox=checkbox), code="""` instead of `CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2,     checkbox=checkbox), code="""`

Comment: I am using bokeh 0.12.3. Not sure why I was using the older version of the example. I tried adding `from_coffeescript`, and it solved the problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem I ran into [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40592165/1562285). It has to do with the way JavaScript checks `in` works. It checks whether 0, 1 or 2 is in the `checkbox.active` array indices.

I solved it like by either switching to `CoffeeScript`, or by using `checkbox.active.indexOf('0')>-1)` as test. Both methods work