# Using the results of an interactive plot to update a second graph on a grid using Bokeh and CustomJS

Tags: python-3.x, callback, bokeh, bokehjs

I have an interactive Bokeh plot that uses CheckboxGroup to plot experimental additive values of different sources. In the background I have stationary plots of theoretical requirement values.

I want to be able to, e.g. 
1.click on sourceA and sourceB resulting in the plot of sourceA+sourceB - I have 8-9 sources and already have this working
2.use a linked plot that shows the percentage error of this combination relative to all the theoretical requirement values.

I don't know JS so, can't really understand how to use this dynamic value for another plot.

Callback for the first part of the problem is as follows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455722/8565759

I can't really show an image of the actual results, the data is export controlled.